# Android Canvas focus in selected area

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, paint

I'm trying to achieve this effect:

[image]

The idea is that I want to cover an `ImageView` with a partial transparent layer, but not all of it. Somewhere there is an area (circle or rectangle), that should be completely transparent. I tried it using this lines of code:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), paint);
paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
canvas.drawCircle((int) x, (int) y, 50, paint);
```

but it didn't work since under the circle there is the rectangle.
Is there anyway to achieve what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer.
You can achieve this my making a CustomImageView and do as follow.

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

private Paint paint;
private Paint transParentPaint;
private Canvas tempCanvas;
private Bitmap emptyBitmap;

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));  //Semi TransParent Paint

    transParentPaint = new Paint();
    transParentPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    transParentPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));//This is necessary to make the portion transparent. Otherwise it will show Black.
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    emptyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    tempCanvas = new Canvas(emptyBitmap);
    emptyBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    // tempCanvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
    tempCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
    tempCanvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 100, transParentPaint); // Set the circle at the middle of the Canvas.
    canvas.drawBitmap(emptyBitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

}

Add this CustomImageView to your layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<transparent.example.com.partialtransparentview.CustomImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/your_image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It will work as you expected.